# Android Studio: Module not specified

Tags: java, android, windows, firebase, gradle

Gradle version: 8.5
Java version: 21.0.2
Android Studio version: 2021.1.1 patch 3

I honestly have no idea what I did its been broken for so long... I can remember trying to setup firebase console for authentication through google, then everything started breaking... Now I've spent 30 hours trying to fix it myself...

I'm very confused with all the gradle files.

This error is how all the confusion started...
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "HabitHero"
include ':app'
```

**build.gradle (project-level)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0-alpha10'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.4.0-alpha10' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.4.0-alpha10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (app-level)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0-alpha10'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    namespace 'com.example.habithero'

    compileSdk 34
    
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.example.habithero'
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testApplicationId 'com.example.habithero'
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'

}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:21.0.0'
    
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.7.0"
    
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1"

}
```

**ActivityMain.java**

```
package com.example.habithero;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    
    private HabitFrag habitFrag = new HabitFrag();
    private DailiesFrag dailiesFrag = new DailiesFrag();
    private TodosFrag todosFrag = new TodosFrag();
    private RewardsFrag rewardsFrag = new RewardsFrag();
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    
    // Helper method to show the PopupWindow
    void showPopupWindow() {
        // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
        View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.image_popup, findViewById(R.id.main_layout), false);
    
        // Create the PopupWindow
        PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
    
        // Set background color for the popup window (optional)
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    
        // Set animation style for the popup window (optional)
        popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
    
        // Get references to the views inside the popup layout
        ImageView imageViewReward = popupView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewReward);
        TextView goodJobMessage = popupView.findViewById(R.id.goodJobMessage);
        Button closeButton = popupView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
        TextView congratsText = popupView.findViewById(R.id.CongratsText);
    
        // Set layout parameters for each view
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams congratsTextParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        congratsTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        congratsTextParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 120);  // Adjusted top margin
        congratsText.setLayoutParams(congratsTextParams);
    
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.CongratsText);  // Positioned below Congratulations!
        imageViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        imageViewReward.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
    
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams goodJobMessageParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        goodJobMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageViewReward);
        goodJobMessageParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        goodJobMessageParams.setMargins(0, 120, 0, 0);  // Adjusted top margin
        goodJobMessage.setLayoutParams(goodJobMessageParams);
    
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams closeButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        closeButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.imageViewReward);
        closeButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        closeButtonParams.setMargins(0, 240, 0, 0);
        closeButton.setLayoutParams(closeButtonParams);
    
        // Set click listener for the close button
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Close the popup window
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
    
        // Show the popup window in the center
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_layout), Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
        System.out.println("Setting the layout to the activity_main.xml");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
    
    
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_profile) {
    
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfilePage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
    
                    return true;
    
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings){
    
                    return true;
    
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_dashboard){
    
                    return true;
    
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_notifications){
    
                    return true;
    
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout){
    
                    return true;
    
                }
    
                return false;
            }
        });
    
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, habitFrag).commit();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.habits) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, habitFrag).commit();
                    return true;
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.dailies) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, dailiesFrag).commit();
                    return true;
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.todos) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, todosFrag).commit();
                    return true;
                } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.rewards) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, rewardsFrag).commit();
                    return true;
                }
    
                return false;
            }
        });
    
    }

}
```

It also throws me this error when I tried to make a new module and use that one... but it was a grey elephant and not a green android so I don't think I was on the right path... Anyways it gave me this error...

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
> Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

This makes no sense because I have my path set to jdk21 and in my code it says the same...

But regarding the lack of a module... I've deleted "include ':app'" and added it back like the internet suggests, didn't work...

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, but that didn't work either... Now I can't even clean my project the option is just gone.

I tried updating my java... I tried updating gradle... I tried updating jdk and sdk... I am so lost... I would really appreciate some guidance...

Comment: Hey, why do you have `buildscript` in app-level gradle file? it belongs in the project level gradle file!

Comment: Oh. Thank you for letting me know I just made the change!

Comment: And why are you using such high version of gradle and alpha versions of gradle? Did you try downgrading your gradle version to like e.g 8.2?

Comment: Do try changing your gradle version to a lower version along with corresponding gradle plugin version!

Comment: That you Mohammed this actually worked!

Comment: Since it helped, i have posted it as an actual answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have selected a very high version of Gradle and its plugin. You should downgrade the version of Gradle to around 8.2 and update android studio. It should do the trick!